# Using Rosjava Time

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the ClockTopicTimeProvider to get time information, but it's constructor takes a defaultNode. Most of my nodes were launched via nodeMainExecutor,

```
nodeMainExecutor.execute(sensorView, nodeConfiguration);
```

The result of this has a connectedNode, I tried casting this to a defaultNode but that didn't work.  The actual constructor for a defaultNode looks like its definably not something I should be using.

Has anyone had any success getting ClockTopicTimeProvider working? Or knows how one obtains the "defaultNode" For reference I have multiple other subscribers and publishers working, and this is an android application using rosjava.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45067/using-rosjava-time/) by [Jyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2115/jyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should ask the Node for the current time instead of using a TimeProvider directly. You can specify the TimeProvider to use in the NodeConfiguration then use Node.getCurrentTime().

A ClockTopicTimeProvider will be used automatically if the /use_sim_time parameter is true when the Node starts.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1